# Accepting bitcoins payments on website, and providing automated bitcoin transfers between users (with automatic transaction charge)?

Tags: bitcoin

I have a website that I would like to enable bitcoin transactions between users. I would like if possible for these transactions to be automated, and I would like the site to receive a percentage per transaction.

Could someone provide a top-level outline of the technologies involved, and how they might need to interact to provide this service. If it's relevant my website is written in Rudy/Rails.

Comment: You might have more luck in the [Bitcoin StackExchange Beta](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend you to use https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive

Basically, this is what you would do:
- Connect to blockchain's API and ask for a new temporal address, attached to the user who is paying, with the site's address as final beneficiary.
- Give that address to the user, along with any information he needs, and ask him to pay.
- blockchain will notify you when the payment happens. The funds will then be transferred to your (the site's) address.
- You can then send the amount less the fee to the final user.

This is just a rough description. Read blockchain's API documentation.

Comment: That's what I used. Works very well for me.

Comment: while this answer provides the fastest way to achieve your goal, but you should be aware that it is a high risk solution, because all your keys will be stored at Blockchain.info(third party). Instead you may run a bitcoin full-node & use its JSON/RPC interface with whatever backend technology you like.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar website that uses the Coinbase API, definitely worth checking it out. https://coinbase.com/docs/api/overview

Comment: and..  what about the wallet? Does Coinbase keep it online? or you can store offline? I can't find this information at coinbase website.

Comment: They have a vault option now.

Answer (score -2):

yes coinbase keep it online but its highly suggested that you  keep  your  wallet on your desktop and keep tfrring it from coinbase or any other third party hosting service to your desktop wallet.

To create an address , you can create one from settings page.  Coinbase also supports integration  of their service with your website within simple to use user interface to create pay with bitcoin. the process is same like basic paypal payment button integration and even supports callback and subscription service buttons,